# Two equal strings evaluate as not equal in bash

Tags: bash

Code:

```
DKIM_RECORD='v=DKIM1\;t=s\;n=core\;p=MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAr0WehGwX2nEq4WY3OmiGnYtRt2941lJBsoDMV485apTs4MagWxuzRCkil7/A9fV/FJdt+bzRcdgurcZBbrwI5PpfACUP4ghL9ZU8H9lwbWIGNu0hpqEE+0cdigB1S54B7Fj/AXx5hA9nBuNA27KD+hpBx4ToUIDhDFy9A6BodO6yHr/CkccGuZJO7dMPMWyycx+CTaJSB4fDQmwtPbYf9NHaucud0h902DIajfiJpZ4CEvCjNU8pcsAXecCBLqnWLkj2b7AxYpX+A4+z1GR5mul1IQQcfkspm1v/ihdWZ+FogtquMpos9u+6OSnXkQfYW83XED6hNE335kgoSDAWgQIDAQAB'
DKIM_RESPONSE=`dig @ns0.transip.net default._domainkey.randomdomain.nl TXT +short | tr -d '" ' `

if [[ $DKIM_RESPONSE != $DKIM_RECORD ]]; then
    echo "$DKIM_RESPONSE"
    echo "$DKIM_RECORD"
    echo "randomdomain.nl: DKIM failed"
fi
```

Result:

```
v=DKIM1\;t=s\;n=core\;p=MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAr0WehGwX2nEq4WY3OmiGnYtRt2941lJBsoDMV485apTs4MagWxuzRCkil7/A9fV/FJdt+bzRcdgurcZBbrwI5PpfACUP4ghL9ZU8H9lwbWIGNu0hpqEE+0cdigB1S54B7Fj/AXx5hA9nBuNA27KD+hpBx4ToUIDhDFy9A6BodO6yHr/CkccGuZJO7dMPMWyycx+CTaJSB4fDQmwtPbYf9NHaucud0h902DIajfiJpZ4CEvCjNU8pcsAXecCBLqnWLkj2b7AxYpX+A4+z1GR5mul1IQQcfkspm1v/ihdWZ+FogtquMpos9u+6OSnXkQfYW83XED6hNE335kgoSDAWgQIDAQAB
v=DKIM1\;t=s\;n=core\;p=MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAr0WehGwX2nEq4WY3OmiGnYtRt2941lJBsoDMV485apTs4MagWxuzRCkil7/A9fV/FJdt+bzRcdgurcZBbrwI5PpfACUP4ghL9ZU8H9lwbWIGNu0hpqEE+0cdigB1S54B7Fj/AXx5hA9nBuNA27KD+hpBx4ToUIDhDFy9A6BodO6yHr/CkccGuZJO7dMPMWyycx+CTaJSB4fDQmwtPbYf9NHaucud0h902DIajfiJpZ4CEvCjNU8pcsAXecCBLqnWLkj2b7AxYpX+A4+z1GR5mul1IQQcfkspm1v/ihdWZ+FogtquMpos9u+6OSnXkQfYW83XED6hNE335kgoSDAWgQIDAQAB
randomdomain.nl: DKIM failed
```

Somehow both string seem equal, but bash evaluates as inequal. What's going wrong here?

Comment: For me that `dig` command does not produce any output.

Comment: Try running the output through `cat -v` or `xxd` to check for unprintable characters.

Comment: The response from the command contains a little carriage return at the end.

Comment: `md5sum <<< string` can be a good sanity check, too.

Comment: @devnull I don't observe any carriage return, just a line feed which should be stripped by the command substitution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When the right-hand argument of the `!=` is not quoted, it is treated as a pattern to match against, not a literal string to compare to. `DKIM_RECORD` contains a backslash, so when its expansion is interpreted as a pattern, the backslash is used to escape the following character, then is removed. This means the value on the left no longer matches the value on the right. A smaller example should make it clearer.

```
$ foo="x\;y"
$ bar="x\;y"
# Here, the value of foo is matched against the pattern "x;y"
$ [[ $foo != $bar ]] && echo no match
no match
# Here, the value of $foo is compared to the string "x\;y"
$ [[ $foo != "$bar" ]] && echo no match
$
```

You simply need to quote the right-hand argument:

```
if [[ $DKIM_RESPONSE != "$DKIM_RECORD" ]]; then
```

Comment: The great thing about this fine answer is that it explains why `[[ $foo != $foo ]]`.

Comment: Which I myself didn't really understand until a few minutes ago :)